Converting an expression into an einsum
I have the following expression that I need to calculate for some matrices:

I could of course do this using a for loop, but I'm attempting to use the torch.einsum function to calculate this in a vectorized manner. I'm having trouble understanding how exactly I can combine two summations into a single einsum expression.
For reference:

c is a nxm matrix
w is a mxn matrix
X is a n dimensional vector
b is a m dimensional vector
X_tilde is a nxmxn matrix

The overall output of this should be a mxn matrix.
Doing each of the sums individually is simple enough. For example, the inner sum (over l) can be easily written as:
torch.einsum("l..., blmn -> mn", w[k], X_tilde)
However, I can't see a way to combine the double summation into a single einsum expression.

It might be good to cross post this to the stackexchange for computer science https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/search?q=einsum.

The w*x+b can't be done with einsum.
c (n,m)
w (mxn)
X (n,)
b (m,)
X_tilde (n,m,n)

The best I can do is with two temporary expressions.
The l sum is a bit confusing.  I assume l corresponds to one of the n, so I'm guessing sum(l) w, X_tilde is:
temp1 = np.einsum('ij,kij->ki', w,X_tilde) # (n,m)

The expression is b looks more straightforward:
w*x+b
temp2 = np.einsum('mn,n->m', w, x) + b   # (m,)

Combining all 3, I assume k sums over a m dimension.
sum(k) c * sigma * temp1 * temp2
res = np.einsum('im,m,jm->ji', c*sigma, temp2, temp1)

I don't think there's a performance benefit to using just one einsum.  Originally einsum constructed an iteration space consisting of all variables.  That could be quite large if there are many variables, and more than two indices.  More recent versions divide the calculation into pieces (matmul if possible), which you can explore with einsum_path.

Maybe you cando the +b by adding a column/row full of 1 in one of the matrices.
